# Dynamically change php table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

First of all - thank you for your help!:)

I'm trying to create a table according to the user input text.

For example - if the user type 123 I'll print in the `<p>` a table from a sql table associate to that input.

I wrote this code in the `index.php` file:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <script>
  $("#testnum").change(function()
  {
      $("#dates").load("getter.php?choice="+$("#testnum").val());
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="testnum" type="int" placeholder="Insert the test num">
<p id="dates">

</p>
```

And this in the `getter.php` file:

```
<?php
include_once "dbconnect.php";
$testnum=$_GET['choice'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `dates` WHERE testnum={$testnum}");
echo "<table>"
while($result2=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<td>
    <tr>{$result2['date']}</tr>
    <tr>{$result2['testnum']}</tr>
    <tr>{$result2['result']}</tr>
    </td>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

And this is the `dbconnect.php`

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "admin";
$password = "123456";
$dbname = "testdb";
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die ( "DB error" );
// Check connection
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES utf8");
$_POST['con']=$con;
?>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Typo . Variable name is wrong ... setting `choise` vs getting `choice` ;)

Comment: Also Id name is wrong  in javascript .. date vs dates

Comment: For starters you've left yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks. Always sanitise input. Do a quick google on SQL injection and how to protect yourself. Secondly have you checked the query is what you expected and if you run it in PHPMyAdmin it returns results? Also, try `var_dump(mysqli_fetch_array($result);` to see what it is pulling back.

Comment: change $("#date") to  $("#dates")

Comment: Thank you all. I edit the spelling mistakes.

Comment: is it working after changing id /

Comment: It still doesn't work. about the attack - I just trying. of course in the real site I need to pay attention to this issue

Comment: Where does it break? JS fires, PHP returns?

Comment: To many unknowns here. Add some error checking after running 'mysqli_query()` show us the `dbconnect.php`

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I add it. pay attention to the edit..

Comment: Did you check your PHP error log for errors? Something is crashing in the PHP

Comment: Have you checked `page source` in the browser. Do you just get a `<table></table>` returned from the PHP If not then its probably the `dbconnect.php` that is failing

Comment: Is `testnum` an integer or string datatype in your table? These and many other things would be useful to know!

Comment: Your JS is invalid. You are calling `.change(` but never closing that call with an `)`. Open your browser's "developer tools" and check the JS debug console log.

Comment: Your `dbconnect.php` shows a certain lask of attention to detail. Why are you using a `die` on the `mysqli_connect()` and then checking the connection status again with `if ($con->connect_error) {`

Comment: Have you tried any of the things I suggested above???? Or are you just waiting for someone to recode this properly

Comment: Feel free to update your question **with any of the answer to any of my questions**

Comment: update... I had two "phpmyadmin" from different servers open and I used the wrong one. I want to kill myself........ kill...!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I used the wrong "phpmyadmin" DB...
I tried to use the one on my wamp server while I used the names from the online server...

anyone who wants to kill me -
tomorrow 14:00-16:00 near my house